# Reclaim and recheck for transit flight purchased separately and no visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, airports

When people create their own connection by purchasing 2+ different flight operated by different airline, they usually have to claim their baggage and recheck-in.

However, baggage Claim usually located behind Immigration control which means you need a visa to recheck in.

How to claim you baggage and recheck in if you don't have the visa permission?

Comment: If you have been denied a visa then you should not book such an itinerary, unless you can arrange with the airlines to check the bags through to thefinal destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had this concern when traveling through Dubai with a companion who required a visa to enter UAE.  Fortunately our two airlines (Emirates and BA) had a cooperation agreement which allowed us to check us and our luggage through to our final destination.

Failing that, a lot will depend on your passport and the countries you are travelling through.  The UK government for instance has a concession on flights to the U.S. where many nationalities who would normally require a transit visa are allowed to enter for up to 24 hours, provided they have the appropriate visa for the U.S., and can show proof of a departing flight within 24 hrs.

In these situations, the Airlines can help a lot and should be your first port of call. They want your business and they will often do whatever they can to secure your safe and convenient passage.  But ultimately, if you need a visa for your transit location, then the only sure way is to apply in advance for a transit visa.

Answer (score 3):

If the two airlines have an interline agreement and are willing to help, the first airline can through-check your bag onto the second airline. However, many airlines have a policy of not doing this outside special circumstances.

A minority of airports (the low cost terminal at KUL springs to mind) have a baggage claim before passport control precisely to allow this situation.

But if neither of these happens your only option in this case is to approach the airport or airline staff and ask for their assistance. If you are travelling on a dirt cheap ticket, don't expect to get your bag back. But if you have several hours between transits and you speak the local business language, the airport may be willing to find your bag, check it onto the next flight and print your boarding pass.

Comment: Some airports offer a service to collect and re-check your bag for you for a fee, eg [the Marhaba transfer service in Dubai](http://www.marhabaservices.com/english/our-services/meet-greet)

Comment: @Gagravarr Good point